# Prevent insertion of record if sub query return no rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a statement that usually relies on multiple sub queries which need to verify the existence of a record:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, categoryId, ...) VALUES (a, SELECT category FROM bar WHERE categoryId = @categoryId), ...)
```

If the sub query doesn't return a value the statement is still successfully executed because categoryId accepts null values. Is there any way to make the statement fail if the sub query doesn't return a value?

Solutions I'm not looking for:

- `CASE` around the sub query and then return a string, because you might think the data types do not match or use `CONVERT(int, 'ABC')` because that's as close as it gets to throw an error.
- `INSERT INTO SELECT ... JOIN` as the query needs to be generated based on some meta data and I would like to avoid rewriting the creation of the statements.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use a `INSERT INTO ... SELECT FROM` instead.

Comment: That's what I'd like to avoid as it requires a lot of refactoring.

Comment: But it's what you ***need*** to do...

Comment: If `INSERT INTO .. SELECT` is not an option for a reason, you can force the entire INSERT failed by providing an illegal value conditionally. Defaulting to a string longer then the target char column for example  `..VALUES (a, coalesce((SELECT category FROM bar WHERE categoryId = @categoryId), REPLICATE('Err', 300)),..)`

Answer (score 1):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, categoryId, ...) 
    SELECT a, category
    FROM category
    WHERE categoryId = @categoryId;
```

With multiple tables, you would use a `JOIN` of some sort:

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, categoryId, ...) 
    SELECT a, c.category
    FROM category c JOIN
         tablex x
         ON c.categoryId = @categoryId AND
            x.foo = @bar
```

Comment: That's what I'd like to avoid as it requires a lot of refactoring.

Comment: Either refactor now - or refactor later, but refactoring is what you are going to have to do.  I would accept that now and get it done instead of pushing it off to later - as later it will be much more work.  Or - don't allow null values in the table in the first place as it seems you don't want to allow nulls.

Comment: @IJustDontKnow . . . Your only other choice is to introduce `NOT NULL` constraints and have the inserts fail.  That will probably cause the entire batch to fail . . . and you'll have to refactor.